# Lifetime of Graph API reference?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Given I have a Facebook Object ID reference to a Facebook post, say [10153550680320161](https://graph.facebook.com/10153550680320161).  How long will this reference survive?  Until the user deletes it, or maybe earlier or later?

Answer (score 0):

Although you never know if there is any backup/cache still stored somewhere, the ID usually will stop working when the user deletes the post. Until then it should be valid.